# Load and authorize based on custom resource for non model backed controllers with cancancan in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

I have spent ages trying to solve this but have not come to a solution yet.

I have a controller that does not have a respective model. Routing-wise it is nested for members of the `Organization` model. In said controller `@organization` is set via the id in the url.

What I want to do is authorize actions from that controller based on this `@organization` instance with [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/) but I fail to do so.
In the `ability.rb` I want to be able to say something like

```
can [:new, :create], InvitationsController do |organization|
    organization.users.include? user
end
```

I know that I could set `class: Organization` to the `load_resource` callback but this results in it being evaluated by cancancan as if belonging to the Organization class. But this would interfere with the `new` action of the OrganizationController which is authorized differently. I cannot change the method name in this controller as it's inherited from a gem. So I have to figure out some way how to be able to authorize this controller in `ability.rb` based on a customly set instance.

I hope somebody knows how to do this in cancancan, this does not seem to be a too specific use case to me.